# Custom JS is not merged into merged JS file

Tags: javascript, merge-css

I added a custom JS file, that is located under the following:

```
/skin/frontend/theme/theme/js/frontend.js
```

But when I run a speedtest, that file is not compressed and loaded into the Magento merged JS file.
It is just loaded outside the merged file.

How can I add this file, so that it will be added to the merged JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you make Magento load your javascript file? 
Make sure you add the Javascript file correctly inside a layout Xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <name>js/frontend.js</name>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Remove the existing merged Javascript file, clean cache so Magento regenerate the merged Javascript file.